# How can I use RSS for Moodle posts

Tags: rss, feeds, moodle

I want to have an RSS feed for Moodle to know posts from teacher.

Is it possible / How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Moodle docs](http://docs.moodle.org/23/en/Using_RSS_feeds)

> Activities that produce RSS feeds

```
     Blog
     Database
     Forum
     Glossary
```

> Subscribing to RSS feeds
>
> To subscribe to an RSS feed from Moodle, go to the activity, click on
>   the orange 'RSS' button and copy the address from your browser bar to
>   your RSS reader software.
>
> Note: Moodle 2.2 had a bug resulting in the RSS button not being
>   displayed. This bug is resolved and fixed, see MDL-30202 for details.

Comment: what is activity ? I couldn't find RSS button in any page!

Comment: The formatting went wrong, the activities are blogs, databases, forums and Glossaries.  They may not have been enabled on the moodle you are looking at.